# Is it possible to specify viewBox in CSS?

Tags: svg

Is it possible to specify the viewBox attribute on an SVG tag?

I've tried view-box, viewbox, and viewBox and none are applied.

```css
#myRectangle {
  viewbox:0 0 1000 1000;
  width:100;
  height:100;
}
```

```html
<svg id="myRectangle" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
        fill="red" stroke="navy" stroke-dasharray="2" stroke-width="4"  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at this time. It is proposed for SVG2. More info here: https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/7